# How to get the id of <a> element inside <h2> element in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbytagname

Consider the following example:

```
<h2><a id="anchorid"><a/> Hello world!</h2>
```

I am trying to get the text inside  and the id of a. At this point I only get the text but the id is undefind. The question is how to get the id of the element inside another element?

Bellow my attempts:

```
  var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"); //take all h2
  var headings = Array();
  headings.push(anchor)

  for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
    var c = document.body.children; //take all children, hopegully anchors
    if (c.nodeName == "A"); { //if the el is anchor
      var id = c.id; // get the the id of each anchor
      var text = "";
      var text = anchor[i].innerHTML;
      // if(id!="" ){
      document.write("<br>----------------------------Id of anchor- " + id + "<br>Text of h2--" + text + "<br>------------------------");
    }
  }
```

In my file there are many  headings for this reason i put them in an array() so I can loop and display the text for everyone.

Please, provide some suggestions! Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refined your code and fixed used variables a bit and:

```js
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"); //take all h2

for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {

  var children = anchor[i].children; //take all children, hopegully anchors  
  for (var ch = 0; ch < children.length; ch++) {
    var c = children[ch];
    if (c.nodeName == "A"); { //if the el is anchor    
      var id = c.id; // get the the id of each anchor
      var text = "";
      var text = anchor[i].innerHTML;
      console.log(id, text);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <a id="anchorid">Hello world!</a></h2>
```

But note that this will only work for the immediate children of `h2` tags.

Comment: Can I ask the downvoter what is wrong with this answer? I fixed the OP's code to make the OP understand it better. I know how to rewrite the better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goal with less code.

```
var i, anchors = document.querySelectorAll('h2 > a');
for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
    var a = anchors[i];
    console.log(a.id, a.parentElement.innerText);
}
```

If you are not sure, that a is first child of h2 you can use following selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('h2 a');
```

Comment: This displays only the id of the anchor and i need the text inside the h2, because the anchor is always epty

Comment: @AlisonVilmoreV So just take your innerText from parent element. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AlisonVilmoreV of course we can search all h2 by using and additionaly find link inside of loop by, but you must be sure, that all h2 contain links. Selecting links which contained in h2 directly looks more reliable. Hope this comments doesn't look confusing. :)

Comment: @TahaPaksu no, but why are you asking?

Comment: THe you so much for the help guys!! I solved the problem and now looks great!

Comment: @AlisonVilmoreV Glad to help. You can accept answer if it solves your problem.